# instance.hookValidate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

While updating child table using Sequelize js after updating parent table, i get
instance.hookValidate is not a function error.

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
return Review.findById(review.reviewId).then(function (pl) {
  if (!pl) {
    throw new NotFoundError(util.format('Entity %s with id=%s is not found', modelName, location.locationId));
  }
    return Promise.all([
      pl.updateAttributes(updateAttributes, {transaction: t}),
     /// _upsertReviewLikes(review.likes, t, review)
     //_upsertReviewComments(review.comments, t, review)
    _upsertReviewPhoto(review.photos, t, review)
    ]);
  });
}).then(function () {
    return cb(null);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    if (err instanceof NotFoundError) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    return cb(new InternalError('Error occurred while updating review.', err.message));
  });

function _upsertReviewPhoto(photos, tran, review) {
  if (photos) {
    _.each(photos, function (photo) {
      photo.reviewId = review.reviewId;
    });
    return ReviewPhoto.upsert(photos, {transaction: tran});
  }
  else {
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
  }
}
```

If I uncomment the _upserReviewPhoto it will work fine.
Any help please

Comment: Upsert only works on a single row http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#upsertvalues-options-promisecreated

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem